# How to append text at the end of each line (in-place) using sed or awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Existing table(sam.txt):

```
 36419 36418
 36418 36417
 36417 36416
 36416 36415
```

Desired output:

```
 36419 36418 1
 36418 36417 2
 36417 36416 3
 36416 36415 3
```

I want to append 1,2,3,4 as extra column. I have tried below sed command but I cannot loop line number `$NUMBER` as gives syntax error?

```
linecount=$(wc -l < sam.txt)
for (( NUMBER=1; NUMBER<=linecount; NUMBER++ ))
do  
   sed -i "$NUMBERs/.*/& $b/" sam.txt
done
```

**Update:** Removed vertical bars between cells as it was causing confusion. I kept that vertical bars to render as HTML table but it didn't load as intended.

Comment: `$NUMBERs` is a valid variable name.

Comment: $NUMBER is variable name s is part of syntax.

Comment: How should bash know? Use `"${NUMBER}s"` or `"$NUMBER s"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $0, NR}' sam.txt
36419 36418 1
36418 36417 2
36417 36416 3
36416 36415 4
```

If you want to modify the original file then with GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '{print $0, NR}' sam.txt
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '{print $0, NR}' sam.txt > tmp && mv tmp sam.txt
```

That last script is what gawk, sed, perl, ruby, etc. do behind the scenes anyway, none of them really do "inplace" editing, they all internally use a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

In awk $0 gives the whole line and you can add text as needed.We declare a variable a that we increment before using it which means that it is one on the first line. We then print the whole line + a space the variable a

- we run:

```
~/tests $ cat sam.txt | awk '{ ++a; print $0 " " a  }'
```

Which outputs

```
36419 36418 1
36418 36417 2                                
36417 36416 3
36416 36415 4
```

Comment: My file will not have | i just gave it here in stack overflow for clean formatting. Numbers will be divided by spaces. Your answer isn't working when there are no | vertical bars. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Ok I've removed the line and put a space to separate the columns. It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This replies to the original question.

Instead of running `sed` multiple times, generate a single sed script and run that just once.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
lines=$(wc -l < "$1")
{
    echo '1s/$/C/'
    echo '2s/$/----/'
    for ((n=3; n<=lines; ++n)) ; do
        echo $n's/$/'$((n-2))/
    done
    echo 's/$/|/'
} | sed -f- "$1"
```